# Is it possible to replace schema locations in Suds/python?

Tags: python, wcf, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to hit a WCF service that's being hosted behind a reverse proxy/redirect. The WCF service is reporting the wrong `schemaLocation`, based on which machine it's actually being served from. For instance, I get something like this:

```
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://badhost1.com/service.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://badhost1.com/service.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Now, it shouldn't be `http://badhost1.com`, it should be `http://goodhost.com`. I can open the xsd in my browser if I point it to the goodhost version - obviously the badhost one doesn't work.

Is there a way to replace these bad endpoints with the correct one?

Comment: A while back I did this in a hackish way.. I had a proxy script that would read a local wsdl file and replace the url based on the query string. I would like to see something more elegant also.

Comment: @jordanm, I thought of doing the same thing, like with Flask. Turns out it's even easier - see my self-answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the one can create [plugins](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#PLUGINS). This one is an easy one:

```
import re
from suds.plugin import DocumentPlugin

class FixUrls(DocumentPlugin):
    def loaded(self, context):
        context.document = re.sub(r'badhost\d', 'goodhost', context.document)
```

And then it's called a la:

```
client = Client(url, plugins=[plugin])
```

That's all it takes!